# How can I find datasets with conditions automatically?

Tags: dataset, numeric, categorical-data, mixed, opendata

I want to find two open mixed datasets(categorical and numerical)
with over than 10000 observations. Each categorical have 3-5 levels 
and the mixed datasets do not have more than 5 categorical variables.
Every mixed datasets have a specific response and others variables 
should be the x variables. How can I find the open datasets?

Comment: You could try asking in the StackExchange [Open Data](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Thank you !! Sorry, I am a beginner in using stackoverflow.